# Search if file exists in Nexus

Tags: maven, jenkins, gradle, jenkins-pipeline, nexus

I'm using Nexus to store the artifacts generated from maven (and also gradle).

As I'm trying to automate the process with Jenkins I would like to check if a file exists before uploading it. I've found [this plugin](https://github.com/chonton/exists-maven-plugin) for Maven but it only works if you execute a normal "mvn install" (it fails doing "mvn clean install").

I've also check the [nexus search api](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api/search-api), but it seems a little complex to manage that request and the response from the jenkinsfile.

Does anyone knows another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you know the artifact's coordinates you can directly ask nexus for the file which will return a *404 NOT FOUND* of the file doesn't exist, use the URL: `http://{nexus.hostname}/repository/{repository.name}/{group.id}/{artifact.id}/{version}/{artifact.id}-{version}.jar` You don't have to actually download the file, use a *HEAD* request instead.

Alternatively you can change *Deployment policy* of your repository to *Disable redeploy* and any attempt to deploy an existing artifact will fail, so you'll achieve the same result as you're trying.

Comment: If you need to check the snapshots the second option does not really apply. The HEAD request seems to be the best option IMO.